# How do I get around the error "Error in WMA(x$Raw_HMA, n = sqrt(50)) : Length of 'wts' must equal the length of 'x' or 'n'"?

Tags: r, technical-indicator

I am trying to calculate the HMA for a technical indicator project, and I've gotten to the last calculation I need. When I run the code, however, I am presented with an error every time stating that the length of 'wts' must equal the length of 'x' or 'n'. I performed the previous calculations without a problem so I am confused as to why this one line of code will not run.

Here is my code:

```
x <- Cl(stock_data) #create a container that contains the initial data, intermediate calculations, and the final technical indicator for convenience. x will eventually become the input argument to the function implementation of the technical indicator
  names(x) <- "close" #rename the data column to make the code general so any stock's data can be inputted easily

  x$WMA_1 <- WMA(x$close, n = 25) #create the WMA(n/2)
  x$WMA_2 <- WMA(x$close, n = 50) #create the WMA(n)

  x$Raw_HMA <- (2*x$WMA_1) - x$WMA_2 #create the raw HMA used to calculate the final HMA

  x$HMA <- WMA(x$Raw_HMA, n = sqrt(50))
```

> Error in WMA(x$Raw_HMA, n = sqrt(50)) : Length of 'wts' must equal the
> length of 'x' or 'n'

I've tried changing x$Raw_HMA to a vector and numeric value, and I also tried specifying wts to equal the same as n, but no matter what I try I end up with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying an integer value for the `n` parameter to `WMA` will resolve your issue:

`x$HMA <- WMA(x$Raw_HMA, n = floor(sqrt(50)))`